# Using setAttribute() on object from XPathEvaluator

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, xpath

I have some troubles with use `evaluate()` function on `XPathEvaluator()` object.
My code looks like:

```
var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
var result = evaluator.evaluate("//div[@id='header']/div[4]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
result.setAttribute("style", "background: red; outline: blue solid thick;");
```

`evaluate()` don't return object which can be used by `setAttribute()` function.
I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath.
How to get correct object on which can be used `setAttribute()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setAttribute` on element nodes. The `evaluate` method does not return an element node or a node list, instead it gives you an [XPathResult](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult-singleNodeValue) object. So you want

```
var div = document.evaluate("//div[@id='header']/div[4]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
if (div !== null) {
  div.setAttribute("attribute-name", "attribute-value");
}
```

Comment: When I type:
`try{
     var result = evaluator.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 
    }
    catch(err){
     alert("ERROR!\n" + err.message); 
    }`
I get: *evaluator.evaluate is not a function*

Comment: Well I would simply used the `evaluate` method exposed on DOM document objects, as shown in my post. I have also prepared http://jsfiddle.net/J5LRh/, works fine for me with Firefox, Opera, Chrome. So my suggestion for `evaluate(...).singleNodeValue` is fine, as far as I can tell. As for using `setAttribute`, I prefer using DOM properties e.g. `element.align = 'right'` or `element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'`, but with Firefox `setAttribute` should do as well (once your code has selected an element node).